# Setting up ad hoc wifi connection

Tags: 10.10, networking, wireless, network-manager

I am connected to internet via a USB EVDO interface on my laptop.
I am trying to setup an ad-hoc connection so that I can use internet on my smart phone as well.
For this I clicked on network manager applet and then `Create new wireless connection`
After setting up connection I started to receive notifications in loop with a delay of 2/3 sec:

```
[Connection name] connection established
[Connection name] Disconnected
....
```

My wifi adapter info as by lspci
05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100

How to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use the 'Internet Connection Sharing Concept'
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

Answer (score 1):

My experience with nm-applet to date has shown that it can't cope with ad-hoc networking at all (nor with IPv6, but that's another issue).

The best advice I can offer is to shut down nm-applet with `sudo NetworkManager stop` and try to set up the network manually with iwconfig and ifconfig.

If that does not work, you might consult the documentation for your wireless driver to ensure that the driver supports ad-hoc networking on the device. IIRC some Linux drivers do not support the full functionality of the device (for example, no promiscuous mode on my ra2870sta.)